# sqldeveloper outputs correct result for count(*) while sqlplus results zero

Tags: oracle

I am getting different output for count(*) in sqlplus and in sqldeveloper.
The Database is Oracle 11G.

SQL Developer

```
Select count(*) from table1 where web_ck_d = to_char(sysdate-1,'DD-MON-YY');
Count(*)
1083171
```

Sqlplus

```
SQL> Select count(*) from table1 where web_ck_d = to_char(sysdate-1,'DD-MON-YY');
COUNT(*)
      0
```

The table has NUM_ROWS-357238869, BLOCKS-14978755, PARTITIONED-YES in all_tables.

Not understanding why sqlplus is resulting 0.
Please help.

Comment: Have you made any uncommitted changes in one of them?

Comment: Why are you storing a date as a varchar?

Comment: All the changes are committed. I am checking this last 3 days. For other tables there is no issue and outputting correct result in both sqlplus and sqldeveloper.

Comment: You might be referring a wrong table, check the synonyms and also try schemaname.tablename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use custom date formats, and if oracle does not find it suitable, it will go and look for default date formats in sessions.

Sql-developer has its own session and sqlplus has its own. Sql developer's date format is specified in NLS date parameter and you can check it from `: Tools > Preferences > Database > NLS`.

You can check the date in sql plus using following query

```
select sysdate from dual;
```

And you can set the desired date format as follows:

```
alter session set NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT='DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF';
```

You can use your desired format here.