# SQLPLus vs SQLDeveloper behavior

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I'm experiencing a different behavior between SQLPlus and SQL Developer.

Example data:

```
create table test (
  INIT_DATE DATE
);

INSERT INTO test(INIT_DATE) values (sysdate);
COMMIT;
```

Now I run the following query (notice we're doing an unnecessary to_date because INIT_DATE is already a date):

```
select to_date(INIT_DATE, 'dd/mm/rrrr') from test;
```

The result is:

- SQLPlus => Return 20/09/16
- SQLDeveloper => Throw ORA-01861

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25841250/sqldeveloper-outputs-correct-result-for-count-while-sqlplus-results-zero), so in SQLDeveloper I changed NLS>Format Date to 'DD/MM/RR' and now SQLDeveloper return 20/09/16.

But, if in SQLDeveloper I change NLS to 'DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SS' again, and I change the query mask to 'DD/MM/RR', SQLDeveloper return an error again:

```
select to_date(INIT_DATE, 'DD/MM/RR') from test;
```

- Can anyone explain this behavior?
- Why SQLDeveloper throw an error if the query mask is 'DD/MM/RR' but not when NLS is 'DD/MM/RR'?

Comment: Why you try convert INIT_DATE column into DATE type through TO_DATE function if this column already has DATE type?

Comment: This conversion is an error. The fact is that a materialized view with this error was installed in production because it was executed with SQLPlus, but now can not be re-installed using SQLDeveloper.

I want to understand the differences between SQLPlus and SQLDeveloper and so I prepared these tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try convert DATE to DATE through TO_DATE function, but TO_DATE function arguments are strings and as result Oracle convert INIT_DATE column to string and then pass this string into TO_DATE function.

If you use implicit conversion 'string to date' or 'date to string' , then Oracle use the default date format. In different environments default date format may be different.

Try to use an explicit conversion and an appropriate format.
For example:

`select to_date(to_char(INIT_DATE, 'dd/mm/rrrr'), 'dd/mm/rrrr') from test;`

Answer (score 2):

Use `TO_CHAR` instead of `TO_DATE`. `TO_DATE` function converts char argument in specific format given by second parameter to date value.

Your statement

```
select to_date(INIT_DATE, 'DD/MM/RR') from test;
```

does first implicit conversion to char, because INIT_DATE is a date. This conversion is in nls default format, depending on your machine settings.

Comment: To see the steps of implicit coversion, first try SELECT to_char(sysdate) FROM dual; Then realize that this is the string you are passing to your to_date() call.